# How to decide to use siblings or parent/children relations in vapor?

Tags: database, fluent, vapor, vapor-fluent, server-side-swift

I have a table named posts, and users can add any post to his favorites. From the perspective of the post, this is User(Parent)/Post(children) relation. But a post can be added to any user's favorites, in this case, should I use the siblings relation?

Here is post Model:

```
final class Post: Model, Content {
    
    static let schema = "posts"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: Keys.title)
    var title: String
    
    // one-to-many relationship...
    @Parent(key: Keys.author)
    var author: User
    
    // many-to-many relationship...
    //    @Siblings(through: PostFavoritesPivot.self, from: \.$post, to: \.$user)
    //    var users: [User]
 }
```

Here is User model:

```
final class User: Model, Content {
    
    static let schema = "users"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    // one-to-many relationship
    @Children(for: \.$author)
    var favorites: [Post]
    
    // many-to-many relationship
    // @Siblings(through: PostFavoritesPivot.self, from: \.$user, to: \.$post)
    // var favorites: [Post]
    
    // which relationship should i take?
}
```

Here is pivot Model if i choose siblings relations:

```
final class PostFavoritesPivot: Model {
    
    struct Keys {
        static let postId: FieldKey = "post_id"
        static let userId: FieldKey = "user_id"
    }
    
    static let schema = "post-favorites-pivot"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Parent(key: Keys.postId)
    var post: Post
    
    @Parent(key: Keys.userId)
    var user: User
}
```

And there are some similar questions, like thumbs-up to a post, follow some users...

I've been wondering for a long time, thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you specify all the dependencies that should exist between your tables? This would make the task much easier. For now it seems that since there are many users liking one and the same post, this is a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: thanks, and i edited this question for some code in.@Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of relationship you use entirely depends on how you expect the models to be linked. In your case, a post can only be created by a single user and a user can create one or more posts, so that's a one-to-many or parent-child relationship.

For liking a post, a user can like or more posts and a post can be liked by one or more users, so that's a many-to-many relationship or sibling relationship.

Just because there's already an existing relationship between a user and a post (creating a post) doesn't mean you can't model different, additional relationships between the same models.

Comment: Thanks man! I have another question on my mind. I use the Parent-Children relationship to represent the relationship between User and Post, can I remove this relation, just add a `user_id` field with UUID type in Post model? like this: `@Field(key: "user_id") var userId: UUID`. this will remove the relation in database too, there are no Link between Post and User table, and when I want query posts of a user, I use filter like this: `.filter(.\$userId == clientUserId)`, Is this option feasible? Which option is better? thanks again.

Comment: Whether you use `@Parent(key: "user_id")` or `@Field` doesn't matter to the DB layer. I suggest you keep it as a parent in your model code so you get all the Fluent stuff. When you want to query the posts for a user you can do `.filter(\.$user.$id == clientUserID)`

Comment: okay，I will keep it， I appreciate your help.